# Having problems with Azure AD, Angular 2 and preflight is invalid (redirect)

Tags: f#, azure-active-directory, adal, preflight, suave

Right now I am not having a great time integrating Angular 2 and Azure AD.

Steps to reproduce error:

1. I have created an Angular 2 front end, Web API(suave.io) and it deployed Azure
2. I have setup Azure AD on the Web Site and Web API
3. Followed this article:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/04/26/using-adal-with-angular2/

4. I get the bearer Azure AD token (great)
5. I then call the Web API and I am getting

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://#### /groups/. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
This is related to this issue.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

My Angular 2 code is this:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
headers.append("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + this.adalService.accessToken ); 

return this._http.get(this.API_BASE + `groups/`, { headers: headers})
.map((response: Response) => response.json())
```

This call removes the Authorization token and sends an Option call. I believe the request fails because there is no authentication header and AD rejects it before it gets to the Web API.

This is the request being now sent from chome:

```
OPTIONS /groups/ HTTP/1.1 Host: dev-api-integration-####.azurewebsites.net Connection: keep-alive Access-Control-Request-Method: GET Origin: http://localhost:4200/ User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization Accept: */* Referer: http://localhost:4200/ Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

My web config has:

```
<httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
<clear />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200/*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Authorization, Content-Type" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
</customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

What can I do? This is a major issue for me at the moment. I guess more and more people will be using Angular 2 and AD integration in future. Any hints or ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you show how you have setup authentication on the API? Seems like it is returning a redirect instead of the typical response.

Comment: I am actually using suave.io passthrough on azure opposed to web api with Azure AD turned on. I am thinking I may have turn off Azure AD on the service and implement it via the web.config and code.

Comment: @Stuart Would you mind sharing the address was redirect from and to?